# Execution Dependency Chain for Image Layout Transitions (and correct use of VkPipelineStageFlagBits and VkAccessFlagBits for that case)

Tags: vulkan

Due to custom-framework-related reasons, I can not extend the command which performs image layout transitions by memory barriers (i.e. I can not specify access flags). The image layout transition code is fixed to the following:

```
void perform_image_layout_transition(VkImage theImage, VkImageLayout oldLayout, VkImageLayout newLayout, ...)
{
    VkImageMemoryBarrier barrier = {};
    barrier.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_IMAGE_MEMORY_BARRIER;
    barrier.oldLayout = oldLayout;
    barrier.newLayout = newLayout;
    barrier.srcAccessMask = 0;
    barrier.dstAccessMask = 0;
    barrier.image = theImage;

    vkCmdPipelineBarrier(..., VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_TRANSFER_BIT, VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_TRANSFER_BIT, ... , 1, &barrier);
}
```

If I want to/have to create memory barriers, I would create an execution dependency chain like follows:

```
// 1. Synchronize with whatever comes before
VkMemoryBarrier memBarrBefore = {};
memBarrBefore.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_MEMORY_BARRIER;
memBarrBefore.srcAccessMask = VK_ACCESS_MEMORY_WRITE_BIT; // Make previous writes available
memBarrBefore.dstAccessMask = 0; // No need to make memory visible; if it is available, that's fine.

vkCmdPipelineBarrier(..., 
    previousStageToSynchronizeWith,
    VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_TRANSFER_BIT,
    0,
    1, &memBarrBefore, 
    ...
);

// 2. Layout transition
perform_image_layout_transition(...);

// 3. Synchronize with whatever comes after
VkMemoryBarrier memBarrAfter = {};
memBarrAfter.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_MEMORY_BARRIER;
memBarrAfter.srcAccessMask = 0; // Memory is already available. Hence, no need to specify an access mask.
memBarrAfter.dstAccessMask = VK_ACCESS_MEMORY_READ_BIT; // Make memory visible to the subsequent command

vkCmdPipelineBarrier(..., 
    VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_TRANSFER_BIT,
    subsequentStageToSynchronizeWith,
    0,
    1, &memBarrAfter, 
    ...
);
```

My question is: Is this a viable approach to synchronize the stage `previousStageToSynchronizeWith` with `subsequentStageToSynchronizeWith` making all memory from the former available, and visible to all caches of the latter?

I am not certain if the execution dependency chain over `VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_TRANSFER_BIT` is the right approach/choice. Could I also use a different pipeline stage to create such an execution dependency? Or is `VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_TRANSFER_BIT` the only possible choice? Or is it even wrong, maybe?

---

**Follow-up question based on krOoze's answer:**

Let's assume an updated version of `perform_layout_transition` which uses `VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_BOTTOM_OF_PIPE` as suggested:

```
void perform_image_layout_transition(VkImage theImage, VkImageLayout oldLayout, VkImageLayout newLayout, ...)
{
    VkImageMemoryBarrier barrier = {};
    barrier.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_IMAGE_MEMORY_BARRIER;
    barrier.oldLayout = oldLayout;
    barrier.newLayout = newLayout;
    barrier.srcAccessMask = 0;
    barrier.dstAccessMask = 0;
    barrier.image = theImage;

    vkCmdPipelineBarrier(..., VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_BOTTOM_OF_PIPE_BIT, VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_BOTTOM_OF_PIPE_BIT, ... , 1, &barrier);
}
```

Does that really synchronize properly with subsequent `TRANSFER` operations - i.e, e.g., two subsequent `vkCmdCopy*` operations with a layout transition in between? With the original version, the execution dependency chain from
`before -> TRANSFER -> TRANSFER -> TRANSFER -> TRANSFER -> after` is obvious.
But with the updated version it would be
`before -> TRANSFER -> BOTTOM -> BOTTOM -> TRANSFER -> after`.

Does `vkCmdPipelineBarrier(..., VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_BOTTOM_OF_PIPE_BIT, VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_BOTTOM_OF_PIPE_BIT, ... , 1, &barrier);` really ensure that -- in the example of two subsequent `vkCmdCopy*` operations -- the second `vkCmdCopy*` waits until the layout transition is done?

What I can't get my head around, in particular, is the following (i.e. this is my personal mental model which must be wrong at some point):

1. First transfer command runs through the stages: `TOP -> TRANSFER -> BOTTOM`.
2. In between comes NO command (?) only a layout transition, that does not run through any stages (?)
3. Second transfer command runs through the stages: `TOP -> TRANSFER -> BOTTOM`.

Now, if I use the updated version which makes an execution dependency chain between `BOTTOM` and `BOTTOM`, can it not be that the image layout transition has not yet completed before the second transfer command's `TRANSFER` stage starts? Synchronizing `BOTTOM -> BOTTOM` would only mean that the layout transition is performed after the first transfer command's `BOTTOM` and before the second transfer command's `BOTTOM` stage, or does it? Where am I wrong?

---

**Clarification question:**

In my original question (topmost), I was considering the following situation:

```
vkCmdCopy*(...);
vkCmdPipelineBarrier(..., TRANSFER, TRANSFER, /* memory barrier to make memory available, but no layout transition */);
perform_image_layout_transition(TRANSFER, TRANSFER, ...);
vkCmdPipelineBarrier(..., TRANSFER, TRANSFER, /* memory barrier to make memory visible, but no layout transition */);
vkCmdCopy*(...);
```

Then, it was proposed to use `BOTTOM_OF_PIPE` stage for the image layout transition, which would come down to the following:

```
vkCmdCopy*(...);
vkCmdPipelineBarrier(..., TRANSFER, TRANSFER, /* memory barrier to make memory available, but no layout transition */);
perform_image_layout_transition(BOTTOM_OF_PIPE, BOTTOM_OF_PIPE, ...);
vkCmdPipelineBarrier(..., TRANSFER, TRANSFER, /* memory barrier to make memory visible, but no layout transition */);
vkCmdCopy*(...);
```

And after a great description of a mental model w.r.t. pipeline stages, I still don't see the two `vkCmdCopy*` commands being synchronized properly with the layout transition in between them.

The spec says:

> An execution dependency chain is a sequence of execution dependencies that form a happens-before relation between the first dependency’s A' and the final dependency’s B'. For each consecutive pair of execution dependencies, a chain exists if the intersection of Bs in the first dependency and As in the second dependency is not an empty set.

Wouldn't that mean that `vkCmdPipelineBarrier(..., TRANSFER, TRANSFER, ...)` and `perform_image_layout_transition(BOTTOM_OF_PIPE, BOTTOM_OF_PIPE, ...)` would fail to create an execution dependency chain since the intersection of their stage flags is an empty set? Furthermore, the first `vkCmdPipelineBarrier` wouldn't form an execution dependency chain with the second `vkCmdPipelineBarrier` since they are not a "consecutive pair"?!

The following version would maybe/probably work:

```
vkCmdCopy*(...);
vkCmdPipelineBarrier(..., TRANSFER, BOTTOM_OF_PIPE, /* memory barrier to make memory available, but no layout transition */);
perform_image_layout_transition(BOTTOM_OF_PIPE, BOTTOM_OF_PIPE, ...);
vkCmdPipelineBarrier(..., BOTTOM_OF_PIPE, TRANSFER, /* memory barrier to make memory visible, but no layout transition */);
vkCmdCopy*(...);
```

Maybe, however, this is the version that was meant by krOoze all along?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks to me like it should work (plus minus formalistic Issue [KhronosGroup/Vulkan-Docs#1193](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/Vulkan-Docs/issues/1193)).

But it defeats the point of using Vulkan. You have three barriers where there should be one (or less with batching). And you use the more brutal access masks. And being instead part of render pass could be better (virtually free as part of load\store op) on some platforms. You are either asking Vulkan driver to be extremely smart (which it should not be), or this will hurt performance. That is not a great start for the framework, and amounts basically to only checking the Vulkan checkbox, while such naive implementation probably performs worse than OpenGL.

> I am not certain if the execution dependency chain over `VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_TRANSFER_BIT` is the right approach/choice.

Assuming the barriers are immediately next to each other, semantically the choice of the chain stage should not matter.

Best Practices layer though might complain with a warning if it sees you transitioning to non-transfer image layout, while the stage is transfer.

I would prefer to use `BOTTOM_OF_PIPE`. Though if you cannot change those stages in the `perform_image_layout_transition`, then you have no choice.

---

Yes, I think your mental model of a pipeline is wrong (and I think it is a common mistake). You think of a pipeline as a FSM (or a flow-chart). But it is not a FSM (despite deceivingly having the same graphical representation). It is literally a "pipeline".

In FSM you would start at 
TOP, then you would go through all the stages, then you would reach the `BOTTOM`. And then you would be forever done. But that is **not** what a pipeline is.

Pipeline works differently. All the stages of pipeline just are; they always exist, and they are always all "executed" at any given time. They never begin and they never end. Think of a pipeline as the board of a board game.

The Vulkan Action Commands breed queue operations, which go through the pipeline stages, like a pegs on the board. A queue operation starts execution at `TOP` when it is submitted, and goes through the stages it needs, then reaches `BOTTOM`, which means the command finished in full and could be removed from the board.

Also keep in mind the commands (pegs) can be in a range of stages at a given time. Typically on modern GPU `vkCmdDraw` starts some vertex shaders, at some point it starts invoking fragment shaders (so it is in **both** VERTEX and FRAGMENT stages), then it at some point it runs out of vertices (so it quits VERTEX stage and is only in the FRAGMENT stage).

What a dependency (Subpass Dependency, or Pipeline Barrier) does is only introducing a game rule that one peg must not reach a certain field if another peg have not yet reached certain other field on the board.

So it completely does **not** matter whether there are no commands in a given stage or not. That is not even a thing you can express in the new mental model I have given you. Your concern is only an artifact created by your mental model.

With the new mental model it is perfectly normal the dependencies would be have `BOTTOM`. It just introduces a rule preventing certain commands reaching a certain stage, until certain other commands reach the required stage. It does not matter what the stage is, nor wheter there is some command that "can execute the stage" there.

Per spec, dependencies chain as long as their stage masks are a subset. And when their chain it means they act as a singular dependency that has `src` of the first dependency, and has `dst` of the second dependency. So two dependencies that form a chain behave like three dependencies; as the two dependencies in isolation, and as the chain dependency.

---

```
vkCmdPipelineBarrier(..., TRANSFER, TRANSFER, ...);
perform_image_layout_transition(BOTTOM_OF_PIPE, BOTTOM_OF_PIPE, ...);
```

would still form a dependency chain, because(spec [VkPipelineStageFlagBits](https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.2-extensions/html/vkspec.html#VkPipelineStageFlagBits)):

> Including a particular pipeline stage in the first synchronization scope of a command implicitly includes logically earlier pipeline stages in the synchronization scope. Similarly, the second synchronization scope includes logically later pipeline stages.
>
> However, note that access scopes are not affected in this way - only the precise stages specified are considered part of each access scope.

Intersection of `TRANSFER`|`BOTTOM` with `BOTTOM` equals `BOTTOM`.

And yes, the `(TRANSFER -> BOTTOM) -> (BOTTOM -> TRANSFER)` is what I suggested. Basically any `(TRANSFER -> X) -> (X -> TRANSFER)` would be technically valid. Your use case is bit of contrieved so it is bit of a speculation. But if your barriers are back to back, I would prefer `X = BOTTOM` as a defensive measure. It is hard for a driver to misinterpret it; it should mean no-op. And as bad as your use-case is, maybe it makes it a slightly bit better (or maybe not). Though one has to consider the two original barriers act as the chain as well as the original (so as three individual barriers). If you have some other stuff between the barriers, maybe `X = TRANSFER` would be better. `TRANSFER` does not interact with `COMPUTE` nor any of the Graphics stages as shown [here](https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.2-extensions/html/vkspec.html#synchronization-pipeline-stages-types). The later is the way I would normally prefer when [working with WSI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61319050/wsi-synchronization-subpass-dependency-and-link-to-color-attachment-output). In the end you need to try and measure.

Comment: Yes, I am aware of the brutal access masks, namely `VK_ACCESS_MEMORY_READ_BIT` and `VK_ACCESS_MEMORY_WRITE_BIT`. Those are just an example and can be changed to something tighter. The question is about the dependency chain w.r.t. `perform_image_layout_transition`. Such a dependency chain split into three barriers with `srcAccessMask = 0` and `dstAccessMask = 0` must come down to the very same as using only one barrier after command parsing, doesn't it?

Comment: Why would `BOTTOM_OF_PIPE` be better? I thought that is something like a non-stage and can, therefore, not be used to create an execution dependency chain.

Comment: @j00hi Because `dstStage = BOTTOM_OF_PIPE` means "nothing". It would be harder for a driver to misinterpret it. `TRANSFER` means you intend to do some `vkCmdCopy*`. Also if you actually have something inbetween the barriers (or it gets added in the future), then `BOTTOM` does not block it (because it is not blocking anything).

Comment: Does that mean that an image layout transition does not qualify as a `TRANSFER` operation? What if I actually had some operation that must complete before the image layout transfer happens, wouldn't `BOTTOM_OF_PIPE` then fail to wait on the previous operation (or previous operation's memory to become available, for that matter)?

Comment: @j00hi Image layout transition does not qualify as any operation. It simply piggy backs on the memory dependency. It happens after the source sync scope and before the destination scope (i.e. it does not happen in any particular stage).

Comment: @j00hi "Such a dependency chain split into three barriers [...] must come down to the very same". That is a dangerous assumption. Driver is discouraged from being smart in Vulkan. It is supposed to not waste any CPU double-guessing what you have written in your code and ideally just do it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and comments they are (as always) very helpful. I've added a small follow-up question. May I ask you to have a look at it?

Comment: Thanks once again for the detailed answer. Have you considered writing a Vulkan book? :) Sorry that I am overly verbose in this question, but I really want to get to the bottom of this... I have added a "clarification question".

Comment: @j00hi Yes, I have considered it. Then I also considered that I am a lazyass. Avoid too much back-and-forths on SO. I will amend answer once more, but consider making new and atomic questions instead.

Comment: You know it's the right thing to do, do you?! :) Existing Vulkan books are pretty bad. Just let me know where I can pre-order or fund your book if it's going to happen!

Comment: @j00hi I am very competitive. I would have to make it worse than they did! I have sposor links at the homepage in my profile if you want.