# WSI synchronization subpass dependency and link to color attachment output

Tags: c++, vulkan

I think I do understand how Vulkan synchronization works, but I do have a problem of understanding the synchronization with the WSI.

The the [Synchronization Examples](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/Vulkan-Docs/wiki/Synchronization-Examples), we can find this code

```
/* Only need a dependency coming in to ensure that the first
   layout transition happens at the right time.
   Second external dependency is implied by having a different
   finalLayout and subpass layout. */
VkSubpassDependency dependency = {
    .srcSubpass = VK_SUBPASS_EXTERNAL,
    .dstSubpass = 0,
    // .srcStageMask needs to be a part of pWaitDstStageMask in the WSI semaphore.
    .srcStageMask = VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_OUTPUT_BIT,
    .dstStageMask = VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_OUTPUT_BIT,
    .srcAccessMask = 0,
    .dstAccessMask = VK_ACCESS_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_WRITE_BIT,
    .dependencyFlags = 0};
```

According to me, it should be something like that :

```
VkSubpassDependency dependency = {
    .srcSubpass = VK_SUBPASS_EXTERNAL,
    .dstSubpass = 0,
    // .srcStageMask needs to be a part of pWaitDstStageMask in the WSI semaphore.
    .srcStageMask = VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_BOTTOM_OF_PIPE,
    .dstStageMask = VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_OUTPUT_BIT,
    .srcAccessMask = 0,
    .dstAccessMask = 0,
    .dependencyFlags = 0};
```

Indeed, since we are going to WRITE into the attachment, there is no need to use a `WRITE_BIT` (meaning make writes available) in the `dstAccessMask`.

But the true issue is in the `srcStageMask`.

I understand why the `dstStageMask`  is `COLOR_ATTACHMENT_OUTPUT_BIT`. It is because it is okay to have the prior stages working since we don't touch the attachment.

However, for the `srcStageMask`, I did not see anything about the link between WSI and the `COLOR_ATTACHMENT_OUTPUT_BIT`. To me, the layout transition must appear at the end of the presentation, and just before the beginning of the `COLOR_ATTACHMENT_OUTPUT` stage.
And the end of presentation, for me, should be represented by `BOTTOM_OF_PIPE` and not `COLOR_ATTACHMENT_OUTPUT`

Where am I mistaken?

Comment: Where does Window System Integration come up in this question? I don't see you creating a display or surface, or manipulating a swapchain in some way. So it's not clear where WSI is involved in this synchronization.

Comment: Yes indeed, my question is not asked correctly. I wanted to say that when you want to use the swapchain image that was presented before, you must use the subpass dependency given in the question to be sure that the layout transition happens at the good time. Else, you can fall in a case that you transition a layout during the presentation, that may lead to an Undefined Behaviour

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Indeed, since we are going to `WRITE` into the attachment, there is no need to use a `WRITE_BIT` (meaning make writes available) in the dstAccessMask.

I am not exactly sure of your logic here. It should be `WRITE` exactly because we are going to write to the attachment.

It would perhaps help describe what is happening here (from [krOoze/Hello_Triangle/doc](https://github.com/krOoze/Hello_Triangle/tree/master/doc)):

[image: swapchain image sync]

The `VkSubpassDependency` chains of the the semaphore (via `pWaitDstStageMask`). Then it performs its layout transition. Then it syncs with the Load Op. (Then Load Op happens in the subpass. And subpass `vkDraw`s some stuff into the swapchain image.)

Now assumably (as is typical for first use of the swapchain image) our Load Op is `VK_ATTACHMENT_LOAD_OP_CLEAR`. That means `VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_OUTPUT_BIT` + `VK_ACCESS_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_WRITE_BIT` access.

So:

1. Presentation is gonna **read** the swapchain image, and submit a semaphore signal.
2. We chain our `VkSubpassDependency` to the signal (via `pWaitDstStageMask`). Semaphore signal already covers all memory accesses, therefore our `srcAccessMask = 0`.
3. The Dependency performs its implicit dependency to the Layout Transition (takes your `src`, and invents some internal `dst`), then Layout Transition happens, which reads the image and **writes** it back, then the dependency performs another implicit Dependency (invents some `src` that covers the layout transition, and uses your `dst`).
4. The Load Op happens in the subpass, and you have to make sure explicitly it happens-after everything above. So your `dst` in your Dependency must be `VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_OUTPUT_BIT` + `VK_ACCESS_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_WRITE_BIT` to cover the Load Op.

Now, there are three types of memory hazards: read→write, write→write, and write→read (and read→read is a non-hazard). In WWH something writes a resource, while some other write also writes it. It is not clear which write happens last, so the memory contents becomes garbage. In RWH and WRH read and write may happen at the same time. It is not clear if the read sees the unmodified memory, or the written one (i.e. it reads garbage).

Without an explicit dependency, the Layout Transition and the subsequent Load Op form a write→write hazard. Therefore `dstAccessMask` **must** not be `0` to resolve the hazard and make sure one write happens-before the second one.

(It is perhaps worth noting we introduce the `VkSubpassDependency` solely for the sake of the layout transition. Otherwise the semaphore wait would already be all that is needed. The default is `srcStageMask = TOP_OF_PIPE`, which means without explicit Dependency the layout transition could happen before the semaphore wait, i.e. before presentation finishes reading it; that would be a read→write hazard).

---

> To me, the layout transition must appear at the end of the presentation, and just before the beginning of the `COLOR_ATTACHMENT_OUTPUT` stage. And the end of presentation, for me, should be represented by `BOTTOM_OF_PIPE` and not `COLOR_ATTACHMENT_OUTPUT`

We have little bit of choice here: `pWaitDstStageMask = dependency.srcStageMask = ?`

Now our situation is this:

```
vkBeginCommandBuffer();
[possibly vkCmdDispatch()?]
vkBeginRenderPass();
vkCmdDraw(); // does vertex shading + fragment shading, then color writes
vkEndRenderPass();
vkEndCommandBuffer();

vkQueueSubmit(.pwaitDstStageMask = ?);
```

If we use `VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_OUTPUT_BIT`, then the semaphore wait does not block starting the hypothetical `vkCmdDispatch()` (`VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_COMPUTE_SHADER_BIT`). And the Subpass Dependency `src` does not force it to finish neither. Great!

The Stage used should not be any earlier stage than `VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_OUTPUT_BIT`. E.g. with `VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_ALL_COMMANDS` the semaphore wait would unnecesserily block the `vkCmdDispatch()` as well as vertex and fragment shader of the `vkCmdDraw`. Meanwhile we need the swapchain image only when we actually need to write it at the Load Op (which you can imagine happens when the `vkCmdDraw()` gets to the point it needs to perform color writes).

Now, we could choose `VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_BOTTOM_OF_PIPE`. The semaphore blocks nothing (`dstStage\pWaitDstStageMask = VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_BOTTOM_OF_PIPE` means the same as "nothing"). Great! But the Subpass Dependency now blocks everything (`srcStageMask = VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_BOTTOM_OF_PIPE` means the same as `VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_ALL_COMMANDS`). That means our `vkCmdDispatch` has to finish, before our subpass starts. Not so great...

So, the best practice is to use `pWaitDstStageMask = dependency.srcStageMask = VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_OUTPUT_BIT`.

Comment: Okay, I understand for the first part. I thought WRITE_BIT only means "flush cache" and I did not think about reordering... Thanks for the explanation.

For the srcStage, I begin to understand, but there is something not clear. Why does the srcStage must be the same as the pWaitStage...

Let's say we do not have a vkCmdDispatch, why shouldn't we use `COLOR_ATTACHMENT` for pWaitStage, `COLOR_ATTACHMENT` for the dstStage and `TOP_OF_PIPE` for srcStage.

Since dstStage means here the COLOR_ATTACHMENT_WRITE for the renderPass.

The srcStage here refers to the presentation... So the issue..

Comment: I mean, the srcStage, In your case refers to the dispatch, but, in my case, it does not refers to anything (or the presentation). , so why we must use the same as the pWaitStage...

Comment: @AntoineMorrier If `pWaitStage=COLOR_ATTACHMENT` and `srcStage = TOP_OF_PIPE` that means the semaphore waits in `COLOR_ATTACHMENT`, but the layout transition could start at arbitrary point (e.g. even before the semaphore signals, and so when PE still reads the swapchain image). That means you have a read→write hazard. (BTW, your first comment got snipped or something.). My `srcStage` does not refer to dispatch. Actually it tries to avoid it. If the dispatch wasn't there, `srcStage` could be `BOTTOM_OF_PIPE`. But no reason to do that if there is a better way that works in all situations.

Comment: I understand the issue. So, in a simple case, the `srcStage` does not refer necessarly to a prior cmd... It can refers to a next stage... I think it is this part that I don't understand...
dstStage refers to the stage within the renderPass. But srcStage refers to what here...

To me, if you put TOP_OF_PIPE in srcStage, but COLOR_ATTACHMENT in dstStage, it means that the layout transition will not begin before the renderPass reached the dstStage without caring about what happen before the srcStage...

Comment: before the renderpass wanted say*

Comment: `srcStage` refers to any queue operation in the queue earlier in a submission order limited to that stage. Yes, that is exactly what `TOP_OF_PIPE` means. Except we do care what happens before. We must explicitly make sure that the Presentation Engine stops reading the swapchain image, before the Layout Transition rewrites the image. So we must ensure our semaphore wait happens-before the layout transition starts.

Comment: Yes, I do understand that, but I think I have a mis understanding . Simply put, you said `srcStage` refers to the prior draw call. My pipeline is like this :
drawCall -> presentation -> drawCall. In the second drawCall, the `srcStage`, to me will refer to the firstDraw call, and not to the presentation, however, the semaphore will be signaled when the presentation is over. I do understand that you must not transition your image BEFORE the presentation finished. Again, to me, in such a case, `dstStage` and `pWaitStage`, since they are equal to COLOR_ATTACHMENT... will refer to the same stage.

Comment: However, I do not understand why `srcStage` , if you make it equal to `COLOR_ATTACHMENT` too, will refers to the same stage as `pWaitStage` and `dstStage`...
I think I understand why `TOP_OF_PIPE` is not enough.
But I don't understand why `srcStage`, since, to me, it refers to the firstDrawCall, it will be helpful... Maybe it is because we put the same value as in `pWaitStage` ?

Comment: `dstStage` has nothing to do with it; that is already too late; transiton happens-before it. A Layout Transition (which is a R\W access) is defined to happen-between `src` and `dst` sync scopes of the Dependency. We want to enforce order presenting→(signal→wait→)transition→subpass. Only way to force presenting to happen-before transition is to form an Execution Dependency Chain. To do that the stage bits in `pWaitDstStageMask` must be a non-zero intersection with stages in `srcStage`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212149/discussion-between-antoine-morrier-and-krooze).