# Why are `pWaitDstStageMask` and `srcStageMask` need to be `COLOR_ATTACHMENT_OUTPUT`

Tags: synchronization, vulkan

[krOoze's wonderful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60339191/synchronizing-a-render-pass-layout-transition-with-a-semaphore-in-acquire-pres) made a "click" in my head about how the acquire-render-present synchronization work, but I have one last grievance with it.

It seems like the choice for `pWaitDstStageMask` and `srcStageMask` to be `COLOR_ATTACHMENT_OUTPUT` is arbitrary.

If I set them both to be, let's say for example, `VERTEX_SHADER` it seems to me that it wouldn't be much different because what we synchronize here is the layout transition and the load operation. We can't have the them happen-before the semaphore signal operation so this dependency chain guarantees us that the transition and the load happen-after the semaphore signal and also, since `dstStageMask` is still `COLOR_ATTACHMENT_OUTPUT` it also guarantees that the draw operation happens-after the layout transition and the load operation.

More so, it seems that `pWaitDstStageMask` can be any pipeline stage and `srcStageMask` can be any later pipeline stage than `pWaitDstStageMask` (for example `pWaitDstStageMask = VERTEX_SHADER` and `srcStageMask = EARLY_FRAGMENTS_TESTS`) since a stage in the first synchronization scope of an execution dependency includes all logically previous pipeline stages, and still that wouldn't make a difference synchronization-wise.

The only thing I can think of that may go wrong here is synchronization with the previous frame, but it doesn't seem to be the case because the the dependency graph looks something  like this:

1. (frame 1) vkCmdDraw on image index i (waits for nothing)
2. semaphore signal (not before the zeroth frame's COLOR_ATTACHMENT_OUTPUT)
3. present (not before the semaphore signal)
4. semaphore wait (not before the presentation operations)
5. layout transition and load operation (not before the semaphore wait - regardless of what pipeline stage is used, as long as it is later than `pWaitDstStageMask`)
6. (frame n) vkCmdDraw on image index i (COLOR_ATTACHMENT_OUTPUT isn't before the transition and the load)

As you can see, everything seem to happen in the order it supposed to be.

So my question is why in every single example that I came across `COLOR_ATTCHMENT_OUTPUT` is used? Is it just as an example? If so, wouldn't it be more productive to use a more "neutral" stage like `TOP_OF_PIPE`?

Edit: Also it seems that the Vulkan spec itself [recommends](https://registry.khronos.org/vulkan/specs/1.3-extensions/html/chap33.html#vkAcquireNextImageKHR) this practice so I imagine there must be some reason behind using `COLOR_ATTACHMENT_OUTPUT` for the stages, but I can wrap my head around why

Comment: What about the second part of this krOoze's wonderful answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61319050/wsi-synchronization-subpass-dependency-and-link-to-color-attachment-output/61323662

Comment: @krOoze Thanks! that clears it up. I think that why I got confused is because I looked at the barrier itself as an operation that waits for the semaphore signal, which is not the case.